What should `ICollection<T>.Count` return when the collection contains more than 2^31 elements?
I am implementing a custom collection in .NET, and in doing so, am implementing the ICollection<T> interface by proxy. Because of this, I can't actually avoid implementing this interface. Part of the interface's contract is
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    Int32 Count { get; }
    // ...
}

My collection will be able to hold more than Int32.MaxValue items (in fact, this is an expected use case), however I'm not sure what the right thing to do is when Count exceeds the range of an Int32.
So what should occur when ICollection<T>.Count is called when the collection contains more than 2^31 elements? Return Int32.MaxValue? Throw an OverflowException? Something else?

Throwing OverflowException sounds like a good idea, yeah.

If some Count is required (where you can throw OverflowException), you can implement LongCount property or method which returns long result.

Array.Count simply calls Array.Length, which throws OverflowException (via use of checked)when larger than int.MaxValue.  So you could do the same thing.

Introducing your own ILongCollection<T> is also not a bad idea.

@Ry- On what basis do you feel that an answer to the question can either be correct or incorrect?  How is it asking for anything at all beyond a personal opinion?  Your edit only makes it  even more opinion based.  It's not even trying to pretend to be factual or objective.  It's just, "what feels right to you".  This is textbook opinion based.  As a mod you should really know better.

@Servy: If the answer is that there is no objectively correct answer, that’s fine. Looking at the question in isolation, it’s not opinion-based. (If it were documented on ICollection<T>, that would be the correct answer. “Feels” is nowhere in the question.)

When opinions can be backed with facts, they are more than opinions. It would be a pity if people were not able to provide answers to such an interesting question. Closing this question would be a disservice to the C# community.

@dbc surprisingly the Array.Length property is also implemented here, and the implementation is different. The checked is missing. It's a real head-scratcher to me, how a property can be implemented in two different files of the same partial class.

@Ry- So the; only possible answer to the question is to quote the documentation of the method being asked about, or to say it says nothing?  The question doesn't ask what the documentation says this implementation should be (if it did, that would be useless, but not opinion based) it asks what the reader's opinion on how it should be implementated.

@TheodorZoulias Literally every opinion in the world can be "backed up with facts".  "What should I paint my bike shed" can be answered with facts.   It doesn't make it an objective question.  That you find the question entertaining doesn't make it any less opinion based.  Whether a question is opinion based or not depends on whether answers are verifiable, whether an answer can be determined to be "correct" or "incorrect".   "What's your opinion on how what my program ought to do" is asking for an opinion.  It can't be incorrect.  There can only ever be answers people "like" or "dislike".

@Servy actually I find this question interesting because I'm also writing a collection class that can have more than Int32.MaxValue elements, and I wasn't sure how to implement the Count property. This question already contains valuable information to aid on my decision.

@TheodorZoulias That doesn't make the question objective.  That you care about a particular opinion doesn't make it not an opinion.  There are tons of people that come here wanting to know what programming language they should learn.  They're very interested in the answer to that question, and it's an important and relevant decision for them to make.  That doesn't make it an on topic question for this site.

@Servy avoiding questions like "What is the best programming language?" is exactly why this site doesn't accept opinion-based questions. Such a question can't be objectively answered, and the most upvoted answer will be the answer that endorses the most popular language. This question here is not like that because 1. it is orders of magnitudes narrower, 2. there are no fanboy clubs who support the A or B alternative solution and 3. it is practically feasible to write an unbiased answer that enumerates the advantages and disadvantages of all available options.

@TheodorZoulias No one has claimed that the question is too broad.  Only that it's opinion based.  This question has a bunch of people just stating what their opinion is for a solution with not factual basis.  You claim that won't happen, but it already has.  It's practically feasible to write a an answer enumerating one's opinion for any opinion based question.  That doesn't make the question not opinion based.  Opinion based questions aren't off topic because it's impossible for people to state their opinions on them.

@Servy you are right that the existing answer by Markus Safar is opinionated. Hopefully the next answer will not be. It is possible to write a non-opinionated answer to this question, and the possibility alone justifies to keep the question open. If we were to close all questions that can potentially receive opinionated answers, we should probably close all the questions of this site. At the end of the day what matters is whether a question adds value to the site, and this question does. Contrary to the "What is the best programming language?" question which doesn't.

@TheodorZoulias No, it's not possible to write a non-opinionated answer.  The question is asking for an opinion.  You could have a poorly explained opinion or a well explained opinion, but you can't have anything other than an opinion.  That there is no possibility whatsoever of an answer that isn't just someone stating their opinion is what makes the question merit closure.

@TheodorZoulias It's false to say that all questions are entirely opinion based.  If someone asks how to sort a list, you can determine if any given answer is "correct" or not by seeing if it produces the desired results.  An answer to most questions can be wrong if it doesn't provide the information requested or a solution to the problem described.  No answer to this question can be wrong, only ever an opinion the reader doesn't like.  On topic questions can contain opinions, and how useful a given correct answer is is a matter of opinion, but whether it's correct shouldn't be.

There is no “right” answer because the official documentation is silent on this question. Any possible implementation will fail to behave properly (that is, as documented) in at least one scenario. Therefore, the best implementation of ICollection<T>.Count in your case will depend on how Count is used by your code, either directly or indirectly.
Starting with the obvious, if Count is never used, then it doesn’t matter how you implement the property. You could hide the property with an explicit interface implementation that throws NotImplementedException (serving as a TODO), and revisit this later:
Int32 ICollection<T>.Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

But if Count is called, here are some advantages and disadvantages of the two options you listed plus a couple more:
Option 1: If the count exceeds Int32.MaxValue, then throw an exception (such as OverflowException); otherwise, return the actual count.
public Int32 Count => _count <= Int32.MaxValue
    ? (Int32)_count
    : throw new NotSupportedException();


Advantage: An exception signals that Count’s documented contract couldn’t be fulfilled and prevents subsequent code from silently operating on an incorrect value and possibly producing garbage output.
Disadvantage: Throwing an exception is relatively costly compared to returning a value, and if done frequently, may noticeably degrade performance.
Disadvantage: If you throw an exception, you’re likely going to want to catch it. However, while usages of Count in your own code are easy to spot, usages by framework and third-party APIs may be buried. For example, the LINQ .Any() extension method invokes Count to check whether the collection is empty. If you throw an exception only occasionally, it may be difficult to find all such indirect usages ahead of time and wrap them in try...catch blocks or refactor your code to avoid calling these APIs.

Option 2: If the count exceeds Int32.MaxValue, then return a sentinel value (such as Int32.MaxValue); otherwise, return the actual count.
public Int32 Count => _count < Int32.MaxValue
    ? (Int32)_count
    : Int32.MaxValue;

This is pretty much the opposite of Option 1.

Advantage: Returning a value allows some existing code (like the LINQ .Any() extension method) to work no matter how many items are in the collection.
Advantage: Returning a value is relatively cheap compared to throwing an exception.
Disadvantage: If you return a sentinel value, you’re likely going to want to handle it as a special case. However, while usages of Count in your own code are easy to spot, usages by framework and third-party APIs may be buried. It may be difficult to predict whether such code will behave properly when given your sentinel value—now and in the future. (The current implementation of .Any() happens to work because it only checks whether the count is nonzero.)

Option 3: Unconditionally throw an exception (such as NotSupportedException).
Int32 ICollection<T>.Count => throw new NotSupportedException();


Advantage: Unlike Option 1 and Option 2, unconditionally throwing an exception makes it much more obvious (once you run your code) which framework and third-party APIs use Count, allowing you to refactor your code to avoid calling these APIs.
Disadvantage: You can’t call such framework and third-party APIs (such as the LINQ .Any() extension method) even when your collection contains no more than Int32.MaxValue items.

Option 4: Don’t implement ICollection<T>.
(You ruled out this option in your question. I’m providing it for completeness for anyone else who comes across this question in the future.)

Advantage: This option is the only one that adheres to the Liskov Substitution Principle. It avoids all the problems that arise from implementing a broken contract. For example, the LINQ .Any() extension method is guaranteed to work no matter how many items are in the collection.
Disadvantage: This option disables some performance optimizations that could be available when the collection contains no more than Int32.MaxValue items. For example, .Any() is forced to always allocate an enumerator.


@TheodorZoulias: Thank you for the bounty! I tried to stick to facts and statements no reasonable developer would disagree with, but the downvote wasn't a surprise.

Michael your answer is impressively good, much better than I hoped for. I don't think that anyone had considered the option 3 before you mentioned it. Regarding the voting patterns, yeah, when they repeat themselves with clockwork precision you learn to expect them. Good thing that they don't have much of an impact.

I think the question is more complex than it seems at first...
If you return Int32.MaxValue you would hide the fact that there are more elements in the collection which will lead to errors that are not easily visible in the code, e.g. calculating some average over all items or whatever. It will work but it will yield false results - so it's a very, very bad idea.
I agree with ry's comment that throwing an OverflowException is for sure the better way to go as it clearly indicates that there are more elements than would fit in the Int32 datatype.
I've seen some code (as far as I remember is was an extension method of some sort) that implemented an additional property LongCount which returns an Int64. You could inherit an interface from ICollection<T> (something like IExtendedCollection<T> or whatever) that adds this property. In this way you leave the "problem" to the code using the collection and offer an alternative solution by providing an extended interface. As the interface inherits the original one, your collection will still work everywhere the original interface is expected.
Update:
Found it, it was Enumerable.LongCount
